# jQuery, Ajax and iOS Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, ajax

Has anyone ever experienced any specific problems relating to the use of jQuery, Ajax events and iOS?

I'm working as a web analyst and on our site we are having issues with iOS in the checkout, we are using jQuery and Ajax events to handle the shopping basket in the background, carry the product information from page to page etc and I'm just taking a stab in the dark because I'm pretty sure it's not the html or css that is causing the issue.

The continue buttons that take you to the next page in the checkout use this href:

```
<a href="#" class="something-something">Continue</A>
```

From a little research I found out that a # href just takes the scroll position back to the top, and this does occur on iOS, the html seems to be working, but then the jQuery is supposed to kick in when it detects a click of a href with this class, but it doesn't, scroll position goes back to the top and then nothing happens.

Look I know it's really difficult to make any suggestions without seeing any code, I'm just taking a stab here in the hope someone might go "Oh yeah it could be this".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing href="#" with href="javascript:void(0);"

Answer (score 0):

Add event binding code inside document ready function like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      //Event binding code
});
```